# Transform an element on y-axis and align it left and right to outer element with

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-transforms

When I rotate a div element -6 degrees like that ...

```
.skew-slider {
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
    perspective: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto 60px;
    display: block;
}
.skew-slider .inner-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY( -6deg );
    -moz-transform: rotateY( -6deg );
    -o-transform: rotateY( -6deg );
    transform: rotateY( -6deg );
}
```

... the element rotates correct and the perspective is also correct. So long so good. But the left and right border of the rotated element should be aligned exactly to the outer border without whitespace between or overflow on the right side.

Here is the example: http://websamurai.ch/stackoverflow/skew-slider.html

Has anyone a solution for that?

Comment: You have 100% of the device width set on the parent component `.skew-slider`, then you set the width of grand-child element to have width of 2520px. It's just bigger than it's container.

Comment: Yes right, but this should be this way, because when you hover over the slider with the cursor, the inner div moves. And the goal is, that if you move to the left, the inner div is aligned at the left window border and if you move to the right, the right edge of the div should align to the right side of the browser window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've found another solution, which is working almost perfect. I've added a script which adds the transform-origin z-axis parameter to -1/3 of the window width (even when resizing the window) and the outer borders left and right are now almost exact the same.

The main parts are these in the script:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    $('.skew-slider .inner-wrapper').css('transform-origin', 'center center -' + $(window).width()/3 + 'px');
});
```

and these in the css:

```
.skew-slider {
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow-y: visible;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    perspective: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto 60px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}
.skew-slider .inner-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    -ms-transform: rotateY( -6deg ) scale(0.8);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY( -6deg ) scale(0.8);
    -moz-transform: rotateY( -6deg ) scale(0.8);
    -o-transform: rotateY( -6deg ) scale(0.8);
    transform: rotateY( -6deg ) scale(0.8);
}
.skew-slider ul {
    width: 2520px;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
```

It's not perfect, but I've not found another working solution and it works this way in the view of the usability.

Hier the example: http://websamurai.ch/stackoverflow/skew-slider.html

Answer (score 0):

Adding a `position: absolute; left: 0;` to the element with the class `"skew-slider"` will do the job. 
I tried this approach with the example you provided and it worked.

Comment: This isn't working for me. The element with the class "inner-wrapper" is still not at the left border of the browser, if you go with your cursor to the left side. And the if you go with the cursor to the right side, this is still something missing from the inner div. And this should also end exactly at the right side of the browser, if the cursor is on the right side.

Comment: Have you tried combining this answer and CodeGust answer?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use `transform-origin`

For instance:

```
transform-origin: left;
```

Comment: Looks good so far, transform-origin: left; is working well for the left side. Do you have an idea, how this could working also for the right side?

Comment: @PeterKälin
Should work the same way for the right side, just write "right" instead of "left". Here is more info http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform-origin.asp

Comment: @PeterKälin
For your example, you may try to add x-margins or/and use scale-transform in addition to rotate.

Also, for me `rotateY` works like `scaleX` and rotates nothing. I use `rotate(-6deg)` to rotate an element.

If after rotation anything goas outside the borders, it is possible to correct it with `top:10px;` left:10px;`, for instance.

Comment: You can only set transform-origin to left or right, but not to both at all. Do you have an example of the scale transformation? I have no idea how to work with scale-transform and x-margins, so that the form would give a trapezoid.

Comment: @Peter Kälin if you need the shape of trapezoid: https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/
What exactly do you try to achieve? Why are you using `transform`?

Comment: I use transform, because the inner content has to follow the shape. I tried the css shape method, but the inner div was not following this shape. Here my example: websamurai.ch/stackoverflow/skew-slider.html. Or is there a possibility, that the content of the inner div follows the shape?